# Change distanceFilter for current CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

Want to change distance filter for my current CLLocationManager from inside didUpdateLocations. No changes takes place.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    self.locManager = CLLocationManager()
    if (self.locManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")))
    {
        self.locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locManager.distanceFilter = Double(100)
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    ...

    }
```

desiredFilter is changed inside didUpdateLocations based on device speed and other properties.

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
...
     self.locManager.distanceFilter =  Double(desiredFilter)
...
}
```

Comment: May I know the purpose of changing the `distanceFilter` inside `didUpdateLocations ` method?

Comment: I have some POI near me and I don't need to receive other locations, just after a x meters, to see again if I got close or far away from that POI. I will increase filter value as long as I get far away from that POI and decrease to be more accurate when that POI is near me.

Comment: I have a project in swift project and there I tried to change the `distanceFilter` within `didUpdateLocations :` method and it is working fie for me. Value is changing.

Comment: Well, do you do something else after you change that distanceFilter value, cuz when I set it to Double(5000), it's still activating after 100m.

Comment: No i just assigned it a value line `locationManager.distanceFilter = 25.0`